# Android: How to align an ImageView to the right of a TextView and make sure the ImageView is always visible

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I need to have an Android layout with two views. The first view is a `TextView` while the second is an `ImageView`. The `ImageView` should always be aligned to the right of the `TextView`. The `TextView` should be able to expand to fill any remaining space depending on the size of the text. The `ImageView` should never be hidden by the `TextView` if the text is too big. The text should be tail truncated in this case.

Here's a visual of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="bottom | center_vertical">
        <TextView
             android:id="@+id/myText"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textColor="@android:color/black"
             android:ellipsize="end"
             android:singleLine="true"/>

        <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/myImage"
             android:layout_width="12dp"
             android:layout_height="12dp"
             android:src="@drawable/myImageDrawable"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@id/myText"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The above XML does not work because `TextView` hides the `ImageView` when its text is too big. How can I fix this code? I'm willing to use a different layout as well. Note that the `TextView` must be a single line.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430019/textview-dynamic-width-with-a-view-at-the-end/59430724#59430724) and you can add `android:singleLine="true"` to your `TextView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below xml is enough to achieve what you want. Just set `singleLine` to `true` and use `drawableEnd` to set your image. Also, replace the text in my code with yours. That's all.

```
    <TextView
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=" HehhsasasashasgghgahgshagshgahsghagshaghsgahsghaHehhsasasashasgghgahgshagshgahsghagshaghsgahsgha shgasagsasghag shahsghag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/myImageDrawable"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```