# TextView dynamic width with a view at the end

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two elements, a `TextView` and an `ImageView`. The `ImageView` will be at the end of the `TextView`. The `TextView`'s width will be change based on the text, and the `ImageView` also follows the end of the `TextView`. Like this:

[image]

But the problem is, if the text is so long, the `ImageView` goes out of the screen, like this:

[image]

But it should be like this:

[image]

How can I get this only by XML? I know programatically it can be achieved, but I want a XML solution.

Note: The `ImageView` can be a `Button`, so I can't use `drawableEnd` like solution.

Comment: Show your layout xml.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can try this the key here is `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="lefttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/right"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/left"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/left"
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change layoutDirection to fix the direction of layout, example
[image: img1]
[image: img2]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:gravity="left">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/left"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/left"
        android:text="abc"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="How can I get this only by XML? I know programatically it can be achieved, but I want a XML solution."/>

</LinearLayout>
```