# ConstraintLayout always have ImageView besides TextView of variable width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I can't solve this seemingly simple layout problem:

I have a `TextView` and I want to have an `ImageView` with an icon right to it. I can't use a `CompoundDrawable` because the icon needs to be clickable. 
Also the `TextView` needs to be `wrap_content`, because it has a background.

The text set to the `TextView` is of variable length. If the text is short, the TextView should take only the space it needs and the icon should be right next to it. If the text is long, the icon should be to the very right and the `TextView` taking all the space left of it.

So this is what I want:

[image]

What I've tried:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:text="short text"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tv"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This works for short texts, but when the text is long, the `TextView` takes up all the space and 'pushes' the icon off-screen.

How this can be solved?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430019/textview-dynamic-width-with-a-view-at-the-end/59430724#59430724

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work
[**Update**: - Use Linear Layout Horizontal]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView57"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.8"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView20"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/filled_compass" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: this will push the image out of width as text view is using `layout_width="wrap_content`

Comment: Thanks! I played around with weights too, but somehow missed this solution :)

Comment: @asco if you wanted a solution with weights then you should have mentioned that in your post and as an experienced SO member, do so going forward.

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I didn't want a solution with weights specifically, but one that does what I described.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you can use Guideline with vertical orientation as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/long_text"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" 
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]