# Simple layout TextView and ImageBottom in horizontal line problem

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to set TextView and ImageBottom in horizontal line with width = wrap_content. So I try to use:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/widget_warning"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black"
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

It is works, but if text is big then ImageButton is invisible (if swap ImageButton and TextView then it works perfectly).

For this variant:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/widget_warning"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black"
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

TextView and ImageButton cut off. If use TableLayout I get the same.
[image: Screen shot]

I do not want use weight attribute for both: ImageButton must have wrap_content width.
**I not use support library.** GridLayout not work. RelativeLayout: if text on the left from Button then text use all width and above.
Any ideas?

Comment: Your code looks okay. Can you provide the full xml code?

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430019/textview-dynamic-width-with-a-view-at-the-end/59430724#59430724

Comment: @Mohammed Alaa Yes it is, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `maxEms="18"` or something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxEms="18"
        android:text="Warning, if widget will stipped then try to set the off battery optimization"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

output:

[image]

**edit**: using `ConstraintLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Warning, if widget will stipped then try to set the off battery optimization"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/info"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This is not good solution: user can change font size. Sorry.

Comment: added edit using constraintlayout now i guess might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use android:layoutDirection="rtl" and swap Views. It works perfectly.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black"
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/widget_warning"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```